# How to get details by tapping detailDiclosureButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, mapkit

In my app there are multiple annotations.

```
MapLocation *annotation = [[MapLocation alloc] initWithDictionary:tempDict];
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
[annotation release];
```

MapLocation is the class where i save the information like city,zip,country,address.

There is detailDisclosureButton in the callout of every annotation. This button loads antoher view(ATM_Details).When i tapp detailDisclosureButton i need to pass information corresponding to that annotation to the the class ATM_Details.

This problem drives me nuts. Any help would be appreciated.

I thought to use method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

But i do not have any idea what to implement in this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*MKMapViewDelegate* has a method **mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:**. You can implement this method and get the corresponding annotation by reading the **annotation** property of the **view** parameter.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

    MapLocation *annotation = (MapLocation *) [view annotation];
    // Get the necessary data from the annotation and pass it to ATM_Details
```

Comment: is this like MapLocation *annotation = (MapLocation *) [view.annotation] ??

Comment: No. Both are not same. You have to either use the dot(.) notation `view.annotation` or the objective-C method notation `[view annotation]`.

Comment: Ok. But somehow i need to keep reference of the object from which i created annotation. So in the method - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control , i can use that object. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign tagValue for each button's, and based on the tagValue You can pass the corresponding information to another view.

Comment: In my app number of annotations are varying. Any time i would not have knowledge how many annotations will be there. So assigning tag is something very difficult and unreasonable.